# Isentropic process for incompressible substances

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

What will the plot of an isentropic process for an incompressible substance look like on a T-S diagram?

Comment: Suppose you heat a block of material and then cool it to return to its original temperature.  Does the entropy have to be constant throughout the entire process?

Comment: Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process#/media/File:Isentropic.jpg

Comment: @ChetMiller In an isentropic process for an incompressible substance the process must be isothermal. Now, does this mean that an isentropic process of an incompressible substance on a T-s diagram will be collapsed to a point?

Comment: I suppose you mean heating the block and cooling it in a reversible manner. If that is the case, then obviuosly the entropy will be changing during heating and cooling. But if the block is returned to its initial state at T1, then entropy will obviously return to its initial state.

Comment: It must be collapsed to a point.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

An isentropic process is by definition one that is both adiabatic $Q=0$ and reversible. If the substance is perfectly incompressible (i.e., a rigid body), then there is no expansion or compression work and $W=0$. Then from the first law $\Delta U=0$.

Internal energy is composed of molecular potential and kinetic energy.  A change in molecular potential energy would appear to be ruled out because that requires a change in intermolecular distances, which theoretically can't occur if the substance is considered a perfectly incompressible substance. Thus, since $\Delta U=0$, the change in molecular kinetic energy must also be zero. That leads to the conclusion that there would be no change in temperature or $\Delta T=0$.

What we wind up with is a point on the T-S diagram. What you are describing appears to be an equilibrium state as opposed to a process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot that helped.